# React Component not showing updated state changes from custom Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm trying to get some auth experience and I've got React with React Router, I found a custom [auth check](https://codesandbox.io/embed/protected-routes-v5qxg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) for routes that I thought looked good, and tried to implement. Basically it would sign the user in, change the auth value to true and be able to call on that auth value from the hook to check.

Here's my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-mahavira-2l7ljg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), my problem is I have to use AWS Cognito for this project so the sign in call has to be from an async function and not through a promise...

Clicking 'sign in check' calls `handleLogin` and starts the async function in the `useAuthHook` with `signIn`, which sets `authed` to true via an effect hook. That change is reflected by using the 'auth check' button, but when trying to navigate to a protected route the console logs the default values.

Here's the steps;

```
...
<Button variant="primary" onClick={handleLogin} type="button">
   sign in check
</Button>
...
const handleLogin = () => {
    signIn();
};
```

Now the signIn hook from useAuthHook;

```
async signIn() {
      const user = "totally real"; //AWS await request
      testValue = "a diff string";
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        console.log(authed, user);
        return "/storageSolution";
      }
 }
```

the effect hook that updates a ref hook and a useState hook(testing both cases);

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      authed.current = true;
      setStateAuth(true);
    }
}, [user]);
```

both `stateAuth` and the `authed` ref are returned along with the earlier signIn, and used in `RequireAuth` before my routes;

```
export function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { authed, user, stateAuth } = useAuth();

  console.log(authed, user, stateAuth);

  return authed === true ? (
    children
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/" replace state={{ path: location.pathname }} />
  );
}
```

but clicking `protected route check` after signing in shows default values in the console, whereas clicking `auth check` shows the updates values.

I found https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function this on stale state, but neither of the reasons it gives seem to be the problem. I've got several different ways of updating and reading that value, but none work. What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you expecting two different callers of the hook to have shared state?

Comment: @super I guess since I update authed, and the hook returns authed, I figured it would return the updated value. Do I need another function in the hook that returns an updated value when called?

Comment: Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) *in the question* for the code you've an issue working with.

Comment: That's not how `useState` works. If you call it in two different component, they will have two separate state variables. Which is exactly what you are doing, but the call to `useState` is inside your hook. That will not magically make it shared between the components. They still have separate state.

Comment: @super so the value only returns updated on clicking ```auth check``` after ```sign in``` because that hook is called in the login component only?

Comment: @Katwatsu Exactly.

Comment: Seems you should move the state from `useAuth` to the provider component so a single state value is consumed from the context.

Answer (score 0):

React hooks don't share state. Move all the state and logic from the `useAuth` hook into the `AuthProvider` component. After this is done the `useAuth` hook simply returns the current `authContext` value.

Example:

```
const authContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return React.useContext(authContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const authed = React.useRef(false);
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState();
  const [stateAuth, setStateAuth] = React.useState(false);

  let testValue = "some string";

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      authed.current = true;
      setStateAuth(true);
    }
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <authContext.Provider
      value={{
        authed,
        user,
        testValue,
        stateAuth,
        async signIn() {
          const user = "totally real"; // where the await auth req would be
          testValue = "a diff string";
          if (user) {
            setUser(user);
            console.log(authed, user);
            return "/storageSolution";
          }
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

index.js

Import and wrap the app with the `AuthProvider` component.

```
...
import { RequireAuth, AuthProvider } from "./useAuthHook";
...

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<LoginSignup />} />
          <Route
            path="/storageSolution"
            element={
              <RequireAuth>
                <StorageSolution />
              </RequireAuth>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/secret" element={<SecretRoute />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```